# open IP address or web link in perl script and pass value to it

Tags: perl

I want to open an (IPaddress or web link) in perl script and pass the value of the attribute username to this ipaddress or weblink. Please add necessary config lines into my following perl script with explanation.

Note: In the following script an exe file is made to be executed, i dont want this now.Instead please replace it a configuration to open an ipaddress/weblink and then pass the value of the attribute "username" to this link or IP.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $p;

print "Hello Radiator is executing the exe file via TKs perl scripting \n";

my $user_name = $p->getUserName;
open my $EX1_PIPE, '|-', "exelocation\file.exe $user_name" 
            or die "location\file.exe $!\n";

print $EX1_PIPE "$_\n" for ($user_name);

close $EX1_PIPE or die $!;
```

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: "Please add necessary config lines into my following perl script with explanation." - you will get a better response if you don't demand that people do your work for you.

Comment: "Please" is word used in a request ... if u feel that is a demand that is your problem ... i never asked you to comment/help or for my question in particular have i ... this site is for asking question as far as i have been a user in this website

Comment: you may have used the word "please", but when you say "add the lines of code" it still sounds like you are *asking others to do your work for you*.  The goal of this site is to help you solve your problem, not get someone else to do it for you.  My comment was not intended to attack you but to help you get the most out of this site.  Look at how many down votes and how many votes to close this question received.  Those were people who might have been willing to help you, but were turned off by the way you asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

The script you gave is not functional.

1. `$p` is undef. You will get an error as soon as you call a method on that variable.
2. The string `"\f"` will contain a formfeed, not the character sequence backslash-f. Backslashes introduce escape sequences, or are ignored if there is no such escape sequence. Please use forward slashes to seperate paths, even on Windows.
3. You interpolate `$username` directly into the command string. It would be better to use more arguments to `open`; this will have a better chance to work even if the `$username` contains spaces:

   ```
   open my $EX1_PIPE, "|-", "exelocation/file.exe", $username or die ...;
   ```
4. Your `for ($username)` statement doesn't make sense, as you are using a loop over one value. Do `print {$EX1_PIPE} "$username\n"` directly.

To open a HTTP connection, I recommend using the [LWP](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP) library. You can use the [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) module for complex operations, or use [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aSimple) to easily `GET` a document. You will probably want to pass the username as a parameter in the query string; look into [URI::Escape](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aEscape) or a similar module to escape any special characters.

How the code will eventually look will depend on the interface of the HTTP service.

In general, your workflow will look like this:

1. Make a user agent instance
2. escape the username, and construct the URL
3. fetch that address
4. Check for valid response, and return decoded result.

Consult the documentation of the modules for examples.